# Use value from model, or if it is undefined then use default value

Tags: html, angularjs

Below is my html code

```
<div>IsValid : {{component._isValid || true}}</div>
```

If `component._isValid` is undefined, it should show true but if it is defined, it should show its value. Currently it is showing true only.

Comment: `component._isValid !== false`…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a so simple condition, so you should better use a function in your controller:

```
isValid() {
    return angular.isUndefined(component._isValid) ? true : component._isValid;
}
```

Call it in template with one-time binding if value is not changing:

```
<div>IsValid : {{ isValid() }}</div>

<div>IsValid : {{ ::isValid() }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below line should do the needful. **AngularJS** directly identifies ternary operation in HTML.

```
<div>IsValid : {{typeof(component._isValid) === "undefined" ? true: component._isValid }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead:

```
<div>IsValid : {{component._isValid ? component._isValid : true}}</div>
```